# Nested TabView inside Column widget

Tags: flutter

I trying create a nested tabs. I would like add tabs inside my column widget - not on `appBar` widget. But when I trying it then I have problem with scrolling. ScrollView not working or working only inside the tab. I would like scroll whole Column widget.

This is my widget three.

```
Scaffold
-- SingleChildScrollView
---- Column
------ Container
------- TabBar
------- TabBarView
---------- ListView
```

Do you have any idea how I can scroll all widgets on my page?

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of what you are doing and what is not scrolling correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **slivers appbar** and **sliver tabbar** to get your desired design.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the comment. I tried and looks fine but I have another problem. How I can turn off scrolling when I have empty screen (tab)?

Comment: you can user **physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),** inside your customscrollview when you have no data.